# MySQL - Combining multiple WHEN conditions in CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to combine 2 rows of results into 1 using the below CASE clause. ‘<26’ should only appear once, and the results should be combined.

```
SELECT  
    CASE org.size
        WHEN 0 THEN '<26'
        WHEN 1 THEN '<26'
        WHEN 2 THEN '26-50'
        WHEN 3 THEN '51-100'
        WHEN 4 THEN '101-250'
        WHEN 5 THEN '251-500'
        WHEN 6 THEN '501-1000'
        WHEN 7 THEN '1001-5000'
        ELSE '5000+' END
        AS 'Size',
        COUNT(DISTINCT org.id) AS '# of Companies'
FROM org INNER JOIN usr ON usr.orgid = org.id
    INNER JOIN usr_role ON usr.id = usr_role.usrid
WHERE org.deleted = 0 AND usr.brnd = 1 AND usr_role.role = 1
GROUP BY org.size;
```

Comment: You could simple change the `As 'Size'` to `As 'OrgSize'`, and then group by OrgSize

Answer (score 63, accepted):

how about this?

```
SELECT  CASE 
          WHEN org.size IN (0, 1) THEN '<26'
          WHEN org.size = 2 THEN '26-50'
          WHEN org.size = 3 THEN '51-100'
          WHEN org.size = 4 THEN '101-250'
          WHEN org.size = 5 THEN '251-500'
          WHEN org.size = 6 THEN '501-1000'
          WHEN org.size = 7 THEN '1001-5000'
        ELSE '5000+' END AS Size, ....
```

---

The problem is that you are grouping the records `org.size` causing `<26` at two different groups since they are originally `0` and `1`.

This will work,

```
GROUP BY CASE 
          WHEN org.size IN (0, 1) THEN '<26'
          WHEN org.size = 2 THEN '26-50'
          WHEN org.size = 3 THEN '51-100'
          WHEN org.size = 4 THEN '101-250'
          WHEN org.size = 5 THEN '251-500'
          WHEN org.size = 6 THEN '501-1000'
          WHEN org.size = 7 THEN '1001-5000'
        ELSE '5000+' END
```

Comment: Good thought, but the results still show 2 separate rows both with size '<26'

Comment: Result Set (9 items)  
Size---------- # of Companies
<26 ---------- 17 
<26 ---------- 87 
26-50 -------- 15 
51-100 -------- 13 
101-250 ------- 12 
251-500 ------- 8 
501-1000 ------ 5 
1001-5000 ----- 6 
5000+ ----------5

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot...so you need to SELECT CASE and you need to GROUP BY CASE when using multiple conditions in WHEN clause?

Comment: actually it depends on your needs. `:)` in this case, you need to since there are different values for `sizes`.

Comment: Great stuff! This saves me a ton of time on some reports and keeps things ultra organized