# MySQL with CASE WHEN with multiple values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display the sum of my severity levels.

My Table

```
client    dateadded     problem        level
 abc      2019-02-02    12345a         1
 abc      2019-02-02    12345b         1
 abc      2019-02-02    12345c         2
 abc      2019-02-02    12345d         5
 abc      2019-02-09    12345e         3
 abc      2019-02-09    12345f         3
 abc      2019-02-09    12345g         4
 abc      2019-02-09    12345h         10
 abc      2019-02-09    12345j         8
 abc      2019-02-16    12345x         7
 abc      2019-02-16    12345s         9
 abc      2019-02-16    12345w         4
 abc      2019-02-16    12345bs        5
```

This is my code

```
select client, dateadded, 
count(case when level= '1,2,3' then 1 end) as Moderate,
count(case when level= '4,5,6,7' then 1 end) as Severe,
count(case when level= '8,9,10' then 1 end) as Critical          
from table1 where client = 'abc'
group by client, dateadded
```

I tried

```
count(case when level= '1' and '2' and '3' then 1 end) as Moderate,
```

My desired output

```
dateadded      Moderate    severe     critical
2019-02-02        3           1           0
2019-02-09        2           1           2
2019-02-16        0           3           2
```

Thanks!
Nathalie

Comment: Thx Siva.. sorry :)  Forgot those lines

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991091/mysql-combining-multiple-when-conditions-in-case

Comment: `level IN (1,2,3)`...

Comment: Your cases will never match. I think you are looking for the `IN()` token: `CASE WHEN level IN(1,2,3) THEN 1 END`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with `IN` condition in `case` and group by `dateadded`

```
select client, dateadded, 
count(case when level IN (1,2,3) then 1 end) as Moderate,
count(case when level IN (4,5,6,7) then 1 end) as Severe,
count(case when level IN (8,9,10) then 1 end) as Critical          
from table1 where client = 'abc'
group by dateadded, client
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN level IN(1,2,3) THEN 1 END ... was the way to go.. thanks all!